# What's a better and easier way for writing Lua game data below

Tags: lua, roblox

Everything works fine, but I wonder if there are any other ways that I could write, access, save and load a player's stats in Lua.

I was thinking maybe JSON, but don't quite know how to go about that.

```
local PSName = ["Vist", Lvl, "XP", "XP2", "Silver", "Item"]
local PType = ["BoolValue", "IntValue", "IntValue", "IntValue", "IntValue", "BoolValue"]
local PValue = [false, 0, 0, 75, 100, false]
local DataStore = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("MainStore")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(plr)

local Fl = Instance.new("Folder", plr)
Fl.Name = Mainstats

for i = 1, #PSName do
local create = Instance.new(PType[i].."", Mainstats)
local create.Name = ""..PSName[i]
local create.Value = DataStore:GetAsync(PSName[i])--When the Player leave it save the key as the PSName so it's valid
end
end)
```

(This is not the whole script. The whole script is a lot messier, which is why I was wondering if there's any easier way to write this.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, on ROBLOX you are using the best way, DataStores.

The one other way to save data on ROBLOX is with Data Persistence, though keep in mind it is outdated and not really supported anymore.

Ultimately it is your choice: http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Data_persistence

Comment: Using DP is outdated and a very bad idea. Data Persistance has the habbit of not saving data when the server crashes. It also requires the player to be in-game. You can't save a player's data the moment they leave neither, as you'll risk failing to save the data. DataStores are the best way to store data. They also have _(basicly)_ an infinite storage space. (200k characters per entry, A LOT)

Answer (score 0):

> Everything works fine

No, it doesn't. Let's, to keep it simple, look at saving the levels:

- PlayerA would save its levels in the key "Lvl"
- PlayerB would save its levels in the key "Lvl"

There are 2 big mistakes:

1. If all players use the same data, they'll overwrite eachother's data
2. You actually wrote *Lvl* instead of *"Lvl*" in the table *PSName*
3. A table in Lua is formed using {} brackets, not [] as you did
4. At this point I realised you never wrote a working Lua script.
   That's not a problem, you're trying, which is a good start. The ROBLOX wiki has some nice tutorials that might help you learning Lua.

To make sure players store their data separately, you would combine their userID with the datakey. *(You could use their username, but since you can change your username, that may lead to data loss)*. Your code should look more like this to work properly:

```
local PSName = {"Vist", "Lvl", "XP", "XP2", "Silver", "Item"}
local PType = {"BoolValue", "IntValue", "IntValue", "IntValue", "IntValue", "BoolValue"}
local PValue = {false, 0, 0, 75, 100, false}
local DataStore = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("MainStore")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(plr)
    local Fl = Instance.new("Folder", plr)
    Fl.Name = "Mainstats"
    for i = 1, #PSName do
        local create = Instance.new(PType[i], Mainstats)
        create.Name = PSName[i]
        -- e.g. for "Lvl" we'll use the key "USERID_Lvl"
        create.Value = DataStore:GetAsync(plr.UserId.."_"..PSName[i]) or PValue[i]
    end
end)
```

Mind that DataStores actually allow you to store tables. You could do this:

```
DataStore:SetAsync(plr.UserId.."_Data",{
    Vist = true; Lvl = 0; XP = 0;
    XP2 = 75; Silver = 100; Item = false;
})
local data = DataStore:GetAsync(plr.UserId.."_Data")
print(data.XP2) -- Will print 75
```

This might be actually easier to write, use and maintain.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'll keep trying. :)